# Global import for Swift CocoaLumberjack

Tags: ios, swift, cocoalumberjack

I configured CocoaLumberjack properly using the swift pod.

And I can log whatever:

```
DDLogVervose("")
DDLogInfo("")
```

But I have to in every class to use it:

```
import CocoaLumberjack
```

> Isnt there a way that I can globaly import ?

Answer (score 0):

The only "trick" to have it available in all your classes is to use a pch (precompiled header) and import CocoaLumberjack there. It's a header that gets imported in all your files.

Comment: I have a swift project. and a swift Lumberjack. I don't believe that CocoaLumberjack can be imported in pct file. right?

Comment: as a work around I defind a class and a class function that do the logging. so i can call the class method without an import. classname.methodname

Comment: ya that didnt work for pch file. i used to do that in obejctve c